# Adding mac like gestures in ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, gui, mac, multi-touch, touchegg

I am using ubuntu 18 and trying to use [this](https://www.maketecheasier.com/add-multitouch-gestures-ubuntu/) guide to add mac like trackpad gestures, I did everything and nothing happens. my lenovo laptop supports multi gesture.

What should I do?

Comment: do you see anything if you run touchegg from teh command line?

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte - yes I get the gesture must appear 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
  Name ->  Flick 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
  Name ->  Drag 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
  Name ->  Pinch 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
  Name ->  Rotate 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
  Name ->  Tap 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
  Name ->  Touch

Comment: looks like it needs to be configured.... is that what is printed in the terminal? did you make a config file per the link you posted?

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/abrahammurciano/wuss. its a collection of scripts that can be configured with libinput-gestures that can get some decent multitouch gestures